# Is there a word for a digitally infused or altered analog/traditional painting other than "mixed media?"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am an artist and sometimes take pictures of my manually painted (analog/traditional) artworks, digitally alter them and print them to display on gallery walls. For online displays of the same painting, I take a photo of the printed artwork (not the digital file) to show the tangible canvas/board as it appears. For media, I typically label it "digitally infused mixed media." Is that clear? I feel we need a better word or phrase.

That is not all. Other times, I create the entire composition digitally, print it, and then I paint over the print. I also paint over the photos I take and print. I call that "mixed media: acrylic, spray paint, etc., on top of digital painting or photograph" if it fits on the label. But often, it doesn't fit; I simply call it "mixed media." Again, I feel we artists need better phrases or hyphenated words — something that an average art lover would understand.

Comment: I'd guess "acrylic on digital print", "photograph with overpainting", etc, would be understood and fit on a label. Try asking your gallery/dealer. And it depends exactly what you do, whether there are lots of different types of paint etc per image. Anyhow "infused" is misleading as it suggests some kind of soaking process.

Answer (score 1):

I think that *mixed media* covers too broad a range of techniques, from Picasso's bull's head to Matisse'e snail collages to your work. Depending on what you processes you have used "digitally enhanced photograph", "overpainted digital print", "oil on digital artwork" or something similar may be appropriate. If you do use the phrase "mixed media" then IMHO it needs to be explained.